# Error while open Experience Builder 68514204-225958 (-501528661)

Tags: community, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page, experience-bundle

After successfull deployment of experience bundle when I try to open the site through experience builder - it is not visible and following message appears:

*We had trouble processing the request. We've reported the problem to Customer Support with error ID: 1408910258*

And after refresh:

*An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.*

*Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com! Error ID: 68514204-225958 (-501528661)*

I wonder how to resolve that issue.

Comment: What you've run into here is a [GACK error](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack). There's not much that we can do (>= 99% of us are customers of Salesforce like yourself) with that error code. There are one or two Salesforce employees that can look into GACKs and get more useful information about what caused the error, but for the most part this is something that you need to go through Salesforce's official support channel to resolve.

Comment: If someone else has run into the same issue, then your best chance of finding out what the issue was is to search for the number in the parenthesis (`-501528661` in this case).

Comment: Bad luck. I tried to search for that number but found nothing.

Comment: The Stacktrace -501528661 points to `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: flexipage.common.api.component.designtimeinfo.throwable.DesignTimeInfoServiceException: No module named c:xxxxx found`. If you are comfortable sharing your org ID, I can check the specific module name from our salesforce backend logs.